# Source for a Rashi gem story

Tags: rashi, story-identification

There's [a well-known](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899065250.html) and [widely repeated](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/111831/jewish/Rashi-Rabbi-Shlomo-Yitzchaki.htm) story that Rashi's father Reb Yitzchak deliberately threw a jewel into the sea, intending to make this appear accidental.

What's the origin of this story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R. Gedaliah ibn Yachya (d. 1587) writes in his [Shalsheles Hakabbalah](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=45240#p=96&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) (starts second line from the bottom) that he read this בקונטריס ישן, in an ancient pamphlet.

(It should be noted, though, that R. Gedaliah is in general known to not be that historically accurate in his writings. In this case, in fact, the story goes on to say that Rashi met the Rambam - which is impossible, as the Rambam was born some 30 years after Rashi's passing.)